# Project not opening in browser from the docker image

Tags: docker, image

The build of my Dockerfile was successful but when I run the container, I am not able to access the project on the browser.

My Dockerfile:

[image]

Here is the output after running the command `docker run 7378a7aa2258`

[image]

After going to this link address  `http://172.17.0.2/` :

[image]

Comment: You seem to have attached image files to your question in place of the actual Dockerfile and log output.  Can you [edit] the question and replace these images with plain text?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the port binding, this specifies which ports of your container are available to the outside world.

The correct command would be `docker run -p 3000:3000 7378a7aa2258` and open your browser on `localhost:3000` or `http://172.17.0.2:3000`.

See [docker run documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports)

Furthermore, the EXPOSE 3000 in the **Dockerfile** only serves as a documentation and does not expose the 3000 port from the container. (See [Dockerfile docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose))

Comment: Changed `EXPOSE 3000` to `EXPOSE 80/udp` the error is the same `site can't be reached`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant in my comment, the expose is just documentation and does not actually bind/expose the ports. In orde to expose/bind those you'll need to use the -p 80:3000 param, as shown in the docker run documentation